# Constraints on bitemporal database

Tags: constraints, temporal, temporal-database

### **Background:**

I'm designing a bitemporal database, where we have 1:N relations between bitemporal tables (we also have M:N relations, but they're just modeled with a connector table and two 1:N relations, so I consider them a special case of an 1:N relation).

To illustrate things, let's consider a simple case with two tables:

```
|===============|        |==================|
|   tblOrder    |        |   tblOrderItem   |
|============== |        |==================| 
| - OrderId     |        | - OrderItemId    |
| - OrderNumber |        | - FK_OrderId     |
|===============|        | - Amount         |
                         |==================|
```

`FK_OrderId` is a foreign key to `tblOrder`.

To make this database model bitemporal, I've come up with the following design:

```
|===============|        |==================|        |====================|
|   tblOrder    |        |   tblOrderItem   |        |   tblVersions      |
|============== |        |==================|        |====================|
| - Id          |        | - Id             |        | - VersionId        |
| - OrderId     |        | - OrderItemId    |        | - VersionDate      |
| - OrderNumber |        | - FK_OrderId     |        |====================|
| - VersionId   |        | - Amount         |
| - IsDeleted   |        | - VersionId      |
| - StartDate   |        | - IsDeleted      |
| - EndDate     |        | - StartDate      |
|===============|        | - EndDate        |
                         |==================|
```

### **Explanations:**

- The `VersionId` columns are foreign keys to the `tblVersions` table. For every change in the database, an entry in the `tblVersions` table is created. The current state of the data is then just the sum of all versions. This makes it possible to reconstruct previous states of the database (via a **`WHERE VersionDate < ...`** clause). This is the **transaction time** dimension of the bitemporality.
- The `tblVersions table could also be avoided if we're just including the`VersionDate` column into the two data tables.
- The `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns are the **valid time** dimensionality of the bitemporality. Yes, `EndDate` is kind of redundant, we could model the tables with just `StartTime`.
- The `Id` columns of the two tables are the new primary keys. Because we have multiple rows for the same entity (multiple versions, multiple date ranges in *valid time*), the ID of the entity cannot be the primary key of the table. The columns `OrderId` and `OrderItemId` are the IDs of the entity, but not anymore the primary key of the table. Instead of creating the new primary keys `Id`, we could also have defined the primary key as `(OrderId, VersionId, StartDate)`.
- If an entity is deleted, we just create a new version entry, as well as an entry in the entity table with `IsDeleted = 1`. All other entries in the table (the inserts and updates) have `IsDeleted = 0`.
- The column `FK_OrderId` of `tblOrderitem` references the column `OrderId` of `tblOrder`. This is not anymore a real foreign key (in the sense of a database constraint), since `OrderId` is not anymore a primary key. But it still tells us which OrderItems are part of a certain Order.

This seems to work well, we have created the necessary CRUD queries and are able to read and write bitemporal data.

### **Question:**

**What kind of constraints do I need for that to work consistently?**

I'm not interested in how to implement the constraints (whether to implement them as database constraints like `FOREIGN KEY`s or `UNIQUE` constraints, or `TRIGGER`s, or `CHECK`s, whatever). I just need to know what **types** of constraints I need.

I figured out a bunch of constraints, which I'm gonna post as an answer. But maybe there are more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm using the abbreviation **PIVT = 'point in valid time'**. This denotes a certain point in time on the *valid time* dimension)

Here are the constraints I already thought of:

- **`FK_VersionId`:** Obviously, we need standard foreign key constraints on the `VersionId` columns.
- **Bitemporal uniqueness:** Also, the combination `(OrderId, VersionId, StartDate)` must be unique (and the same for `tblOrderItem`).
- **Valid time serialization:** We need to check that for each entity and each version, there are no overlaps in *valid time*, i.e. the columns `StartDate` and `EndDate` do not overlap, and `StartDate` is always earlier than `EndDate`.
- **Deletion integrity:** We need to make sure that for each entity and each PIVT, there is maximal one row with `IsDeleted = 1`, and if there is such a row, there must not be any version of the entity **after** that row.
- **Referential integrity:** We need to check that for each OrderItem entity, each version and each PIVT, the value of `FK_OrderId` is set to a value that identifies an Order entity which exists at the given PIVT, which has been inserted in an earlier version and which has not been deleted (by setting `IsDeleted = 1`).